# Apk opens and closes when using buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I'm a beginner, and I created an application with simple kivyMD for testing, I tried to convert with buildozer, it doesn't show any errors, and it generates the apk.

when installing the apk on the cell phone, it simply opens and closes without showing any errors

buildozer.spec

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1
```

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class listaScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def dados(self):
        pass
    
class CameraScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Teal'  
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(listaScreen(name='lista')) 
        sm.add_widget(CameraScreen(name="camera"))   
        return sm
    
    def on_start(self):
        pass

    def realizar_pesquisa(self, texto_pesquisa):
        pass

    def abrir_camera(self):
        self.root.current = "lista"
        
    def voltar_menu(self):
        self.root.current = "menu"   
MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "WebReport"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            right_action_items: [["camera", lambda x: app.abrir_camera()]]
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: lista
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 0
                adaptive_height: True
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(67)
            padding: dp(12)
            spacing: dp(12)
            MDTextField:
                id: campo_pesquisa
                hint_text: "Pesquisar"
                mode: "rectangle"
                icon_right: "magnify"
                on_text: app.realizar_pesquisa(self.text)        
<ListaScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Detalhes"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: app.voltar_menu()]]
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Informações do QR Code'
            halign: 'center'
            font_style: 'H6'
        MDLabel:
            id: info_qr_code
            text: ''
            halign: 'center'
```

I looked at the other posts before creating this one, however, I didn't find anything

Comment: Try running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt` with your cell phone attached. Then look at `my_log.txt` for hints about what is happening.

Comment: I did that and what I discovered is that the error is in that line but I can't fix it,        config.read('config.ini')
        db_file = config.get('database', 'db_file')